# ansible looping over nested lists

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have nested lists in group_vars like this:

```
var_name:
- group1:
    - variable1
    - variable2
- group2:
    - variable1
    - variable2
```

and want to iterate over it in jinja2 template to form an xml like:

```
<group>
    <variable> <host>variable1</host> </variable>
    <variable> <host>variable2</host> </variable>
</group>
<group>
    <variable> <host>variable1</host> </variable>
    <variable> <host>variable2</host> </variable>
</group>
```

so i made a nested noop like

```
{% for var in var_name %}
    <group>
    {% for host in var %}
            <variable> <host>{{host}}</host> </variable>
    {% endfor %}
    </group>
{% endfor %}
```

but it's not working, i got

```
<group>
    <variable> <host>group1</host> </variable>
<group>
<group>
    <variable> <host>group2</host> </variable>
<group>
```

looks like host variable containing var variable value, how should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Try this.

First, rename group1 and group2 to "group" like this:

```
var_name:
- group:
    - variable1
    - variable2
- group:
    - variable1
    - variable2
```

Then, change your looping as follows:

```
{% for var in var_name %}
<group>
{% for host in var.group %}
    <variable><host>{{ host }}</host></variable>
{% endfor %}
</group>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `{% for host in var %}` statement.  `var` just resolves to the string `group1` in the first iteration of the loop and `group2` in the second iteration.  This is why you're getting the output you mentioned.

What you want to be doing is using that name as a reference into the `var_name` data structure.  What you want is something along these lines:

```
{% for host in var_name[var] %}
```

This will reference the variables as you have them defined in `var_name`.